# Control FadeIn and FadeOut of images with scroll up and down

Tags: jquery, css, image, scroll, fade

Is it possible to control the fade in and fade out effect of images when you scroll up and down? I want to achieve the following effect. I have a list of vertical aligned images, not all of them are visible on the screen, so i have to scroll though them. If I do so, the images which are moving out of the viewport should be fade out to maybe 50% opacity, and the images which are moving in should fade to 100%. Both Effects, fade in and fade out, should be triggered at a certain point of the viewport, because it can be possible that I have a image of very large height, so it's not very useful if the fadeout effect starts when the top of the image is close to the top of the viewport. It would be better, if the effect could start when the bottom of the image is for example 100px close to the viewport.

Right now I'm using the following code. But I have to be honest, I really don't know how to edit the code to achieve the things I mentioned before.

```
var target = $('div');
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
    if(scrollPercent >= 0){
        target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through each image on scroll and use offset to know when the image gets into viewport. something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
    $('img').each(function(){
       var imgTop = $(this).offset().top;
       // continue your code here to compare viewportTop and imgTop etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to creat a working coding at fiddle? I have to admit I'm not that experienced. Thank you so much